# Transferring data in an array from view to view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, retain

I have a class, call it `Class1`, which contains an array, call it `array1`, as a property, and I retain and synthesize it.

I want to add objects to that array with values I get from other views. So for each view, I reference `Class1`, create an object, and I add the value to `array1` and display it for that particular view. This works!

When I go to the new view, I am required to reinitialize `array1` to copy the new objects to it (or it gives me an error that `array1` is null), but the previous value (the value which was stored in the previous views) is lost. I understand that "retain" is for a specific class, and the array does not retain values for the whole course of the program.

How do I go about this?

Comment: You could store the array using `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider creating a [`singleton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html) class which you can access anywhere in your application. Apple docs have a [`standard approach`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) for creating singleton classes. You can make `Class1` a singleton class.

Comment: haha. wonderful. I shall try this out and get back... if I make a lot of singleton classes, won't life be easy to pass variables and stuff between views ;) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link to Apple's standard approach. +1

Comment: @Legolas Making too many singletons means they all stay in memory as long as your app runs. This could lead to a memory warning and later forced closure of your app. Singletons should be used wisely.

Comment: Thanks man. Could you tell me how this is different / more efficient than NSUserDefaults ?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` might not be a bad option for storing an array but remember it reads and writes to a database periodically although it caches the data. I am not against it but I see it as a place to store your application preferences not a communication mechanism or a storage mechanism either. There are other methods provided for both these purposes. If the data manipulation goes beyond an array i.e. you want the parent class to be available everywhere to manipulate or react to changes I would rather choose a singleton. But far too many singletons are a memory hog if they have lots of data.